# Can't connect to gatt server

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm developing an app that would simulate a Smart Home through BLE technology.
I created an app client and an app server for a lighting service and they worked very fine.

But when I tried to merge the two apps into only one, the client part can't connect to server part **(onClientStatusConnection(): status=133)**. Of course, I used two devices.

I tried my app with nRFConnect app and both client part and server part worked fine, so I don't understand why my app doesn't work.

That's my code on Github: https://github.com/irenetrifi/AtriumProject

 Hope someone could help me.